# IE8 CSS selector ~ (tilde) addresses only first element

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors, tooltip

IE 8 will address only the first tooltip element "a[data-tooltip="sk_5 …" instead the preceeding ones too.

The HTML:

```
<div class="skcontainer">
   <a class="specialClassifications classification classfication_6" href="/de/ueberuns/romantik-siegel" data-tooltip="sk_6"></a>
   <a class="specialClassifications classification classfication_9" href="/de/ueberuns/romantik-siegel" data-tooltip="sk_9"></a>
   <a class="specialClassifications classification classfication_112" href="/de/ueberuns/romantik-siegel" data-tooltip="sk_112"></a>
   <a class="specialClassifications classification classfication_8" href="/de/ueberuns/romantik-siegel" data-tooltip="sk_8"></a>
   <div class="sks sk_5"><span class="inner"><p>'Gelber Schlüssel' für Romantik Hotels &amp; Restaurants mit luxuriösem Angebot. Für Gäste, die höchste Ansprüche an Stil, Ambiente, Genuss und Gastlichkeit stellen.</p></span></div>
   <div class="sks sk_6"><span class="inner"><p>TEXT</p></span></div>
   <div class="sks sk_7"><span class="inner"><p>TEXT</p></span></div>
   <div class="sks sk_8"><span class="inner"><p>TEXT</p></span></div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.sks {visibility:hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 100}
a[data-tooltip]:before {content: ""; position: absolute; visibility: hidden}
a[data-tooltip]:hover:before, a[data-tooltip="sk_5"]:hover ~ .sk_5,
a[data-tooltip="sk_6"]:hover ~ .sk_6, a[data-tooltip="sk_7"]:hover ~ .sk_7,
a[data-tooltip="sk_8"]:hover ~ .sk_8, a[data-tooltip="sk_9"]:hover ~ .sk_9,
a[data-tooltip="sk_10"]:hover ~ .sk_10, a[data-tooltip="sk_11"]:hover ~ .sk_11 {visibility: visible}
```

Any (CSS only) ideas or hints? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, welcome on SO and congrats for making a good question with related code. A good way to share the problem with people is to put your code on a jsfiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can u put whole code in jsfiddle please? I'm not sure if you want to achieve what I think you are. Btw when I turn on IE 8 it won't even start the jsfiddle correctly :DDD

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve and why you are using the rather odd-looking code you have. You have `a` elements with empty content and you have markup errors (attempts at using `p` inside `span`). Class names like `sk_6` suggest that you should take a different approach.

Comment: I tried but IE8 isn't supported. Anyway here we go. Please mind i couldn't test it there: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeg/WL9Sn/9/

THX 4 suport

Comment: The HTML wasn't coded by myself. I rewritten the CSS due to a CSS only approach and i cleaned the HTML for better readability. The purpose is by hovering an image encapsulated by the a to show the tooltip. Changing the HTML isn't possible …

Comment: At jsFiddle it seems to work right. Wich document type are you using? Tried HTML5 with SHIM?

Comment: Doctype is HTML5 and the selectivizr is used for backward compatibility on lt IE9. The solution with SHIM i didn't checked but at present I seriously think about dropping the support on IE8 of this feature since it doesn't effect the usability that much. But thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the tilde is a CSS3 selector, [it is buggy in IE7 & 8](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector). Consider using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) as a way to bridge the gap between IE8's CSS2 capabilities and modern CSS3 selectors.

**Edit based on the rest of the comments:**
If you're considering dropping support for IE8, check your analytics first to make sure too many people won't be affected. If the tilde selector + css tooltips aren't working, you should make sure to add a title to the links so people in IE can still see [admittedly ugly] tooltips.

Comment: It being buggy in IE7 and IE8 has absolutely nothing to do with CSS3. The adjacent sibling selector `+` is part of CSS2 and suffers from the same comment node bug in IE7.

Comment: Thanks, good point. Well at least we can agree that while IE8 may support some CSS selectors, it's still a buggy mess. Some JS may be necessary to get it to fail slightly less.

Comment: I checked the compatibility but didn't thought about the buggy selector support of lt IE9. My decision was based on usage data and the overall functionality will be guaranteed as well. The Tooltips won't even pop up on IE. But I'm pretty glad that all of your lend me a helping …